# How do I disable Xfce display power management in xubuntu 16.04 at the command line?

Tags: xubuntu, display, xfce4-power-manager

Goal:  From the command line, disable the Xfce Power Management setting that controls the display power management.

I've tried to get a list of power management settings from xfce-power-manager but I haven't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 4):

`dpms` is the Display Power Management Signalling.  For the `xfce4-power-manager` to disable it is a simple command mainly just to quit it.

```
xfce4-power-manager -q
```

To re-enable `xfce4-power-manager` it is:

```
nohup xfce4-power-manager & 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

To disable the `dpms` run the following command:

```
xset -dpms
```

To enable `dpms` it is just the opposite:

```
xset dpms
```

Hope this helps!